# Spring Boot + docker-compose + MySQL: Connection refused

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to set up a Spring Boot application that depends on a MySQL database called *teste* in docker-compose. After issuing `docker-compose up`, I'm getting:

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

I'm running on Linux Mint, my docker-compose version is 1.23.2, my Docker version is 18.09.0.

application.properties

```
# JPA PROPS
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming-strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://db:3306/teste?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=rafael
spring.datasource.password=password

spring.database.driverClassName =com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpass
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=teste      
      - MYSQL_USER=rafael
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
  web:
    image: spring-mysql
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - DATABASE_HOST=db
      - DATABASE_USER=rafael
      - DATABASE_NAME=teste
      - DATABASE_PORT=3306
```

and the Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8
ADD target/app.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same issue and in case you do not want to use any custom scripts, this can easily be resolved using health checks along with depends on. A sample using these is as follows:

```
services:
  mysql-db:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=vikas1234
      - MYSQL_USER=vikas
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    restart: always
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost" ]
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 10

  app:
    image: shop-keeper
    container_name: shop-keeper-app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      mysql-db:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://mysql-db:3306/shopkeeper?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: root
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: vikas1234
```

Answer (score 5):

Docker compose always starts and stops containers in dependency order, or sequential order in the file if not given. But docker-compose does not guarantee that it will wait till the dependency container is running. You can [refer](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) here for further details. So the problem here is that your database is not ready when your `spring-mysql` container tries to access the database. So, the recommended solution is you could use [wait-for-it.sh](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/blob/master/wait-for-it.sh) or similar script to wrap your `spring-mysql` app starting `ENTRYPOINT`.

As example if you use `wait-for-it.sh` your `ENTRYPOINT` in your Dockerfile should change to following after copying above script to your project root:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["./wait-for-it.sh", "db:3306", "--", "java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

And two other important thing to consider here is:

- Do not use links they are [deprecated](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/) you should use user-defined network instead. All services in docker-compose file will be in single user-defined network if you don't explicitly define any network. So you just have to remove the links from compose file.
- You don't need to publish the port for docker container if you only use it inside the user-defined network.

Comment: Thanx a lot for this answer that helped me get my docker-compose work. However I have lost a lot of time trying this without success, because the default timeout of 15 seconds in `wait-for-it.sh` was not enough, so I had to increase this. I would not have lost that much time if I knew that this timeout can be changed, can you please update your answer to tell users that default timeout can be changed.

Comment: well at the least, @Moussa, I have read your comment and immediately increased the timeout interval :)

Comment: THANK YOU! I've been trying this for hours. In the docker compose up logs it always showed Mysql Started before the app kicked in so I assumed mysql completely starts, but I was still getting Connection refused! Only by using this script I was able to get it running! BTW on your host change permissions to that .sh script to 777 otherwise you'll get permission errors.

Answer (score 1):

Your config looks nice, I would just recommend:

- Remove `links: db`. It has no value in `user-defined bridge` networking
- Remove port exposing for db unless you want to connect from outside `docker-compose` - all ports are exposed automatically inside `user-defined bridge` network.

I think the problem is that database container takes more time to start than web. `depends_on` just controls the order, but does not guarantee you database readiness. If possible, set several connection attempts or put socket-wait procedure in your web container.

Comment: This indeed sounds like an issue with the mysql container not fully having started yet. You can look into https://github.com/jwilder/dockerize to wait. You'll have to add this application to the image and then wait before starting the java app.

Answer (score 0):

For the connection refuse issue, we need to consider a few things

1. When providing DB URL for Spring application. you need  to specify the ***MySQL service name*** as host

`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://<mysql_service_name_here>:3306/<db_here>`

2. Spring application can be looking for MySQL DB connection before properly starting the MySQL container. To eliminate that issue should spring-app container make wait using  **`healthcheck`** and **`depends_on`** properties on compose file.
3. All two containers should be in the same docker network.

Perfect sample compose file that includes those solutions.

```
version: '3'
services:
  mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql:5.7
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-h", "localhost" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: http_logger
      MYSQL_USER: supun
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    networks:
      - logger-network
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql

  http-logger:
    image: http-logger:v1.8.0
    container_name: http-logger
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    build: .
    depends_on:
      mysql :
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - logger-network
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: mysql
      MYSQL_PORT: 3306
      MYSQL_DB: http_logger
      MYSQL_USER: supun
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password

networks:
  logger-network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  mysql-data:
```

Here is perfectly working spring boot + MySQL volume + docker-compose example.
https://github.com/supunUOM/spring_mysql_docker_volume